# How can I fusion two wizard pages into one?

Tags: inno-setup

I would like to know if there's any way to put SelectProgramGroupPage' content into wizard page' SelectDirPage like this:

[image: Shot from a custom installer]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done directly by Inno's command - these are two separate pages.

But you can achieve the same if you create your custom page - place any components you want to create similar design.
But there is a lot of coding behind it, handling path, creating directories etc etc.

Remember: If you disable standard pages and create custom one you need to handle al situations by yourself.

Comment: Do you know if the code used in the standard pages is available? I would like to see some examples @Slappy

Comment: The code is available in a sense -- Inno is open-source.  However this is not in a form that you can use it from Inno's internal scripting language.